# EXCEL 2010 sum with multiple column criteria range in an OR logic

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have to table which have 5 columns and data shown in the picture

[image: Quest Detail Table].

The rule is basically once someone’s name is in one of the three columns [Edit, Translation or Final Edit], I should add the Word count to them. But if the same name is in 2 of those columns, the word count should be added just once.

Is there a way to count how many words that each person have processed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(($C$2:$C$13 = G7)+($D$2:$D$13 = G7)+($E$2:$E$13 = G7)>0),$B$2:$B$13)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I make one step further? Is it possible to do the same thing if there is another column called [date] added and I wish to know the total word count for each person by month?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it...Lets say you have a date like 2-Nov-2018 for entries...Change your output table and replace "Total Word COunt" by month name i.e. "Nov" and use below formula :

=SUMPRODUCT(--(($C$2:$C$13 = G9)+($D$2:$D$13 = G9)+($E$2:$E$13 = G9)+(TEXT((F4:F15),"MMM")=H8)>0),$B$2:$B$13)